# How to start an IPython MPI cluster?

Tags: mpi, ipython

I am trying to start IPython with MPI engines all on my local machine. I need MPI. [The IPython documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_mpi.html) suggests just running this:

```
$ ipcluster start -n 4 --engines=MPIEngineSetLauncher
```

However it doesn't say what to do after that. For me that results in:

```
$ ipcluster start -n 4 --engines=MPIEngineSetLauncher
2012-10-18 11:07:14,340.340 [IPClusterStart] Using existing profile dir: u'/Users/enos/.ipython/profile_default'
2012-10-18 11:07:14.342 [IPClusterStart] Starting ipcluster with [daemon=False]
2012-10-18 11:07:14.342 [IPClusterStart] Creating pid file: /Users/enos/.ipython/profile_default/pid/ipcluster.pid
2012-10-18 11:07:14.342 [IPClusterStart] Starting Controller with LocalControllerLauncher
2012-10-18 11:07:15.343 [IPClusterStart] Starting 4 Engines with MPIEngineSetLauncher
2012-10-18 11:07:45.348 [IPClusterStart] Engines appear to have started successfully
```

and it just stays there. How do I get an IPython command prompt?

I'm trying this with IPython 0.13 on OSX 10.8 with a 4-core machine.

Comment: Keep reading the page :) There is some sample code under the heading "Actually using MPI".

Comment: @GregInozemtsev that section assumes I have an interactive command prompt, which I don't have.

Comment: You simply start `ipython` in another terminal.  Then the example code creates an instance of Client that connects to the running engines.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the comments, but I think it would be more useful to place it here.

"You simply start ipython in another terminal. Then the example code creates an instance of Client that connects to the running engines. –  Greg Inozemtsev"